# Existence of poles for Dirichlet series of multiplicative functions

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, dirichlet-series

I have a question dealing with the following ANT assignment:

If $f$ is multiplicative with $|f(n)|\le1$ and $F(s)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}$ is analytic around $s=1$, show that $F(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$ iff $\mathbb{D}(f,1,\infty)<\infty$ where $\mathbb{D}(f,g,x)^{2}=\sum_{p\le x}\frac{1-\Re f(p)\overline{g}(p)}{p}$

I got really stuck on this one, the main problem I have is regarding the issues of moving between summing over primes and positive integers, since convergence on one set does not guarantee anything regarding convergence on the other (meaning $\sum_p\frac{f(p)}{p}$ says nothing about $F(1)$ at least as far as I can tell). 
for $\Leftarrow$ assuming $\mathbb{D}(f,1,\infty)<\infty$ we find that $\sum_{p}\frac{1-\Re{f(p)}}{p}<\infty\Rightarrow \sum_{p}\frac{1-|f(p)|}{p}<\infty\Rightarrow \sum_{p}\frac{|f(p)|}{p}=\infty\Rightarrow \sum_{n}\frac{|f(n)|}{n}=\infty$ but again this is insufficient to help solve my problem.

Bottom line : I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me a better direction for solving the problem (or maybe this could work but I'm not seeing something here)
Thanks

Comment: We definitely want to use the assumption that $f$ is multplicative; then $F(s) = \prod_p (1 + f(p)p^{-s} + f(p^2)p^{-2s} + \cdots$ for $\Re s>1$, and you can show that $F(s)$ has a singularity at $s=1$ if and only if $G(s) = \prod_p (1 + f(p)p^{-s} )$ has a singularity there (the quotient $F/G$ is absolutely convergent for $\Re s>\frac12$). By the way, one definitely needs to say "singularity" rather than "pole", since algebraic or logarithmic singularities are quite possible.